# Java - Check if an SqlSessionFactory is valid

Tags: java, sql, mybatis

I generate an `SqlSessionFactory` from an `SqlSessionFactoryBean`, and catch exceptions to determine if it successfully created for a given data-source.

However, I have found that method fails if the database exists, but has no listener. No exception is generated and an exception only occurs later when I actually try create an open session of the `SqlSessionFactory`.

What's the best way for me to check if I am working with a valid database, accepting normal sessions?

Edit: It doesn't actually appear to be that opening a session throws the exception ... it may only happen at my first actual update/retrieve call.

Comment: I might be missing something, but is there a specific reason why opening a session for testing purposes doesn't work for you?

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals It turns out I was wrong about that, but I'd rather not generate dummy connections if there is a more appropriate way to find this information.

Answer (score 0):

Many connection pools have a connection validation query option, which can be configured to execute something simple like `SELECT 1` (depends on the database, of course) to validate the connection is valid. It's the same premise, though: attempt to execute the query and catch the exception.

If you are already using a connection pool, and it supports such an option, I wonder if this would solve your problem.